# SSIS fails to read .CSV file when text (within the defined text delimiters) contains a comma

Tags: csv, import

I had an SSIS job to import a CSV file that worked fine on SQL Server 2008.  Moving to SQL Server 2017 the job fails, as the new version does not see "happy,christmas" as one text field, but as two with missing delimiters. Other tools that I can test (Excel, Access, VBA) all interpret it correctly, ignoring the comma as it is within a text field.

Have I got some setting wrong?  This seems a very elementary failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
"happy,christmas"
```

I assume those fields are quoted in the csv file since they are read correctly by other parsers.

You have to tell the parser to use a quote char / quoted fields.

That parameter seems to be [FIELDQUOTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for bulk insert.

Comment: The CSV file is correctly constructed, that's why it is read correctly by other applications. 
 I think the problem arises because the file contains a text field which is a brief cut and paste excerpt from an email and as such can contain any character. Still, if teh structire is correct, SSIS should handle it.

Comment: @Dougie Indeed, but maybe this is not the default in SSIS while it is in those other applications. Anoter possibility is that this field also contains double quotes which can be escaped with another double quote or a backslash depending on the system they were created.